# Share multiple items (PDF's) with ShareLink and Transferable in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-sharelink, core-transferable

I want to share multiple PDF Documents with apples new ShareLink.
I can share a single PDF Document by making my object transferable using the FileReprestation and giving my object into shareLink:

```
extension item: Transferable {
     public static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        FileRepresentation(exportedContentType: .pdf) { item in
            return SentTransferredFile(item.url, allowAccessingOriginalFile: false)
        }
    } 
}
```

and using ShareLink in my view:

```
 ShareLink(item: item, preview: SharePreview(Text(""))) {
      Label("",systemImage: "square.and.arrow.up")
 }
```

Another working option is giving ShareLink the URL of my PDF.

Now I want to share multiple PDF docs at the same time. I have an Array of Items ([Item]). Sadly ShareLink does not take and array of objects as input...
How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare pdfs array and then pass it to 'items' argument

```
ShareLink(items: transferablePdfs, preview: { _ in
                SharePreview("Share Title")
})
```

You can customize SharePreview for your needs. This sample code is just to show how pass multiple transferable items to ShareLink and share funcionality.